# Can I submerge a polyester shoe underwater to wash it, and for how long?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers

I'm wondering if this will damage the shoe somehow. The shoe doesn't include washing instructions. My shoe actually has four materials listed, they are:

-Polyester
-Polyuretan
-Natural rubber
-Nylon

I don't know any chemistry, I'm ignorant. I think this substances can come in many forms, so there is a lot of uncertainty. But if you answer for at least what the title asks, I'm fine, I'll make more questions for the rest of the materials.

Comment: Have you thought of wiping with a damp cloth?

Comment: @long Yes, but I don't want to do that, thanks. I want to explore this  different method in particular, also if the shoe has sweat and dirt inside that won't take it off.

Comment: It should do no harm, other than possibly removing some dye or sizing (which makes fabric hold its shape), *provided that the shoes are dried thoroughly* afterwards to prevent fungus and bacteria from growing in the wet material and  particularly in the foam insole. Don't use too much heat (much above body temperature), since heat will damage the glues and melt polyurethane.